# Sorting of an array using merge sort

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I have implemented  for merge sort in c , although the code seems to be correct the code does not give me the sorted array rather returns the same array that is given to it, that means my merge function  in not working

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void re_sort(int arr[],int size);
void merge(int left[],int right[],int arr[],int rightlen,int leftlen);

int main(void)
{ 
  int a[10];
  int n;

  printf("enter the number\n");

  scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("enter the elements\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

      {  
         scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      }

    re_sort(a,n);          //merge sort using recursion  

    printf("the sorted list is:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

      {  printf("%d\t",a[i]);

      }


    return 0;
}

void re_sort(int arr[],int size)

{  int mid,*left,*right;
   int k=0;
  if(size<2)            
    return; 

  else 
  mid=size/2;
  left=(int*)(malloc(mid*(sizeof(int))));          // two sub arrays left and right 
  right=(int*)(malloc((size-mid)*(sizeof(int))));

  for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
  { 
    left[i]=arr[k++];
  }

  for(int j=0;j<(size-mid);j++)
  { 
    right[j]=arr[k++];
  }

  re_sort(left,mid);                 //recursion until size becomes less than 2
  re_sort(right,size-mid);
  merge(left,right,arr,size-mid,mid); //both the elements in left and right are merged



}
void merge(int left[],int right[],int arr1[],int rightlen,int leftlen)

{   int arr[100];
    int k=0,i=0,j=0;
    while(i<leftlen && j<rightlen)
    { 
      if(left[i]<= right[j])

      arr[k++]=left[i++];

      else 

      arr[k++]=right[j++];

    }

    while(i<leftlen)
    {
        arr[k++]=left[i++];
    } 
    while(j<rightlen)

    { 
       arr[k++]=right[j++];
    }

    for(int l=0;l<(rightlen+leftlen);l++)
    { 
      arr1[l]=arr[l];
    }
    free(left);
    free(right);
}
```

Comment: `arr[l]=arr1[l];` , after that??

Comment: You're leaking memory on each recursive call ...

Comment: You're also not passing a pointer to the array, you're just passing the array? So you're not actually changing any values. Unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible.

Comment: @dragosht ok so can i prevent that because if i make 2 sub arrays there will always be memory leak

Comment: @Yann4 what do you mean pointer to array? this is correct way to pass the an array

Comment: I'm with you, that is how you pass an array, I was just thinking that it wasn't being changed because you were passing by value, so the original wouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
  if(left[i]<= right[j])
      arr[k++]=left[i++];
  else 
      arr[k++]=left[j++];
```

last `left` should be `right`.

Anyway, where do you `free` the memory you `malloc`-ed...?

Comment: Also `arr[l]=arr1[l];` should be `arr1[l]=arr[l];`

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to `malloc` a new buffer for each sub-array on every recursive call. Remember, `malloc` is quite expensive action, and `free` costs even much more than `malloc`!

The subarrays resulting from recursive splitting do not overlap (except for the result of merge spans over two merged parts). So you never need more than **one** buffer at a time for the merge result **and** that merge does not interfere with any other merge (except with those for which it is a sub-range). As a result it's enough to create just **a single copy** of the whole input array and use both arrays alternatively as a source place and destination place for recursive merges:

```
void merge( int dst[], int src[], int idx1, int idx2, int end2)
{
    int idx = idx1;
    int end1 = idx2;

    while(idx1 < end1 && idx2 < end2)
        dst[idx++] = src[idx1] <= src[idx2] ? src[idx1++] : src[idx2++];
    while(idx1 < end1)
        dst[idx++] = src[idx1++];
    while(idx2 < end2)
        dst[idx++] = src[idx2++];
}

void mrgsrt( int dst[], int src[], int begin, int len)
{
    if(len == 1)
        dst[begin] = src[begin];
    if(len > 1) {
        int mid = len/2;
        mrgsrt(src, dst, begin, mid);
        mrgsrt(src, dst, begin+mid, len-mid);
        merge(dst, src, begin, begin+mid, begin+len);
    }
}

void sort( int a[], int len)
{
  int *tmp;
  if((tmp = malloc(len*sizeof(*a))) != NULL) {
    memcpy(tmp, a, len*sizeof(*a));
    mrgsrt(a, tmp, 0, len);
    free(tmp);
  }
}
```