# Issue with Merge Sort - Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, mergesort

I am following the *Merge Sort* algorithm suggested in *2.3.1* of *Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen*. However, I am not getting the correct output. I am sure there's some silly mistake in here, but I haven't been able to figure that out for some time now. Any help would be really appreciated.

e.g: For input : `5,4,3,2,1`, my output is `3 1 2 4 5` instead of `1 2 3 4 5`.

Assume that the code will be tested for really small numbers, and that replacing the sentinel value ∞ (in the algorithm) by `999` does not affect the program.

Here is the code and the corresponding steps of the algorithm is in comments. An execution of this is [here](http://ideone.com/BoJUSi).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int* A, int p, int q, int r) {       // MERGE(A,p,q,r)
    int n1 = q-p+1;                             //   1. n1 = q-p+1
    int n2 = r-q;                               //   2. n2 = r-q 

    int i,j,k;
    int *L=new int[n1+1], *R = new int[n2+1];   //   3. let L[1...n1+1] and R[1..n2+1] be new arrays

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++)                         //   4. for i = 1 to n1
        L[i]=A[p+i];                            //   5.    L[i] = A[p+i-1]
       //the modification in above line is deliberately done to avoid IndexOutOfBounds when p=i=0 and is not because I forgot to subtract 1               
    for(j=0; j<n2;j++)                          //   6. for j = 1 to n2
        R[j]=A[q+j];                            //   7.    R[j] = A[q+j]

    L[n1]=999; //sentinel                       //   8. L[n1+1]= ∞
    R[n2]=999; //sentinel                       //   9. R[n2+1]= ∞
    i=0;                                        //  10. i = 1
    j=0;                                        //  11. j = 1
    for(k=p; k<r; k++) {                        //  12. for k = p to r 
        if(L[i]<=R[j])                          //  13.    if(L[i]<=R[j])
            A[k]=L[i++];                        //  14.         A[k] = L[i]
                                                //  15.         i = i+1
        else                                    //  16.    else A[k] = R[j]
            A[k]=R[j++];                        //  17.         j = j+1                 
    }

    delete(L);
    delete(R);
}

void mergeSort(int* a, int p, int r) {        // MERGE-SORT (A,p,r)
    if(p<r) {                                 //  1. if p<r 
        int q=(p+r)/2;                        //  2.   q = (p+r)/2 
        mergeSort(a,p,q);                     //  3.   MERGE-SORT(A,p,q)
        mergeSort(a,q+1,r);                   //  4.   MERGE-SORT(A,q+1,r)
        merge(a,p,q,r);                       //  5.   MERGE(A,p,q,r)
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1};
    mergeSort(arr,0,5);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout << arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: "However, I am not getting the correct output." What output are you getting? What's the expected output? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the ideone link for people to see. But for completeness, I'll edit it still. :)

Comment: Also... you don't want to be able to sort numbers larger than 999?

Comment: No. only for small numbers. If required, I can always change the sentinel to the maximum possible integer by calling the library functions. But for now, I just want to sort small numbers.

Comment: Merge sort is nice when for efficiency you can only go forward through the data, e.g. data on tape, or lines of text files, or a linked list. For arrays other sorts are generally better and simpler. Anyway, `std::sort` is the thing.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I was just trying to understand the algorithm, so used an integer array. I am not really implementing any big stuff right now. Otherwise, library calls are really efficient when compared to this.

Comment: What a stupid algorithm! It performs approximately 2N allocations (calls to `new`) for approx. (N log N) items in total; the maximum during the execution is (2 log N) blocks allocated for 2N items (where N is the original array's length). All those allocations require initalisation, which means the whole array is copied (log N) times. And a half of all those allocations are `new int[1]`, which is incredibly ineffective. Withe the properly designed code the whole task can be completed with a **single** copy to a **single** allocated block for N items...

Comment: @AnindyaDutta Hey, you do lots of allocations (`new`), but I can't see where you release allocated blocks (`delete`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive calls to `mergeSort` suggest that `p` and `r` are the indices of the first and last item of a subarray to be sorted:

```
void mergeSort(int* a, int p, int r) {
    if(p<r) {
        int q=(p+r)/2;
        mergeSort(a,p,q);
        mergeSort(a,q+1,r);
        merge(a,p,q,r);
    }
}
```

If so, your call in `main` is incorrect:

```
int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1};
mergeSort(arr,0,5);
```

should be

```
int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1};
mergeSort(arr,0,4);
```

Next, copying the second half is wrong:

```
R[j]=A[q+j];
```

should be:

```
R[j]=A[q+1+j];
```

Note that `p` is an index of the first item in the left half, while `q` is an index of the last item of the left half – so the first item of the right half has index `q+1`, and that should be taken as a base for `+j`.

Finally,

```
for(k=p; k<r; k++)
```

should read

```
for(k=p; k<=r; k++)
```

– `r` is an index of the last item in the right part, so you need to fill the `[r]` position of the merged subarray.

**EDIT**
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995966/733637) to [Sorting of an array using merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403686/sorting-of-an-array-using-merge-sort).

Answer (score 1):

```
L[i]=A[p+i];                            //   5.    L[i] = A[p+i-1]
```

I think this is your problem, you do not follow the algorithm here, by fixing it a little (not using -1 because you start at 0) but in the next loop, you don't +1 when you're also not starting at the same number in the algorithm?

```
R[j]=A[q+j];                            //   7.    R[j] = A[q+j]
```

In the previous loop, you manually correct for starting at 0, instead of 1, but here you do not.

Comment: Changing `R[j] = A[q+j+1]`. When `j=n2-1`, it would mean `A[q+n2]` = `A[q+r-q]` = `A[r]`. For `r=5` (my initial call), this means an `OutOfBounds`.

Comment: @Anindya Dutta It seems correcting for one loop and not for another makes the code inconsistent with the source algorithm no? why don't you just keep the initial values at 1, and change the conditionals from '<' to '<=' so that you can be sure to stay consistent with the algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try by considering all the arrays from indices `[1...n]`. Seems a waste of the `0`th index though. :\

Comment: Haha, yea it does. But hardcoding a fix to one loop, while leaving the other intact (which makes your algorithm different from the original) might cause problems with the logic.

Comment: Indeed, changing `R[j]=A[q+j+1]` did do the work. Thank you. I'm sorry about the part where I mentioned it going `outOfBounds`.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta No problem! Don't forget to choose my answer ;)

Comment: There were two other changes that needed to be done along with that too. The merging needed to be done till `<=r` instead of `<r`, and the array parameter passed in the `main` function needed to be reduced by `1`.